# Laravel вывести данные из 2 таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных, laravel, запрос

Нужно вывести данные в  из 2 таблиц.
Есть таблицы:
alcohols (id; name_alcohol; id_type_of_alcohol)
storages(id; name_storage; possible_places)
storage_info(id_of_storage; id_of_alcohol; count)

Я сделал, чтобы была страница storages, где отображается (id склада, имя склада, места возможно, места занято, подробней), при нажатии на "подробней" тебя бросает на страницу, с id того склада, где уже есть описание склада(id склада, id алкоголя, количество), так вот, вывести id склада и количество не проблема, а вот с id алкоголя проблема, не могу взять в запросе данные из 2 таблиц...
Вот код:

### Controller

```php
    <?php
     
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
     
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;
     
    class StoragesController extends Controller
    {
        public function storages(){
     
            $storages = DB::select("SELECT s.id, s.name_storage, s.possible_places, SUM(sa.count) FROM storage_info sa, storages s WHERE id = s.id GROUP BY id, s.possible_places, s.name_storage");
     
            return view('storages.storages', ['storages' => $storages]);
     
        }
     
        public function storage_info($id){
            $storage = DB::select("SELECT id_of_storage, count FROM storage_info WHERE id_of_storage = $id ORDER BY id_of_storage");
            return view('storages.storage_info', compact('storage'));
        }
    }
```

### storages.blade.php

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Storages</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     
        <h1>Storages</h1>
     
        <table border="2">
            <tr><th>Storage ID</th><th>Storage Name</th><th>Места возможно</th><th>Места занято</th><th>Detail</th></tr>    
        @foreach ($storages as $stor)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $stor->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stor->name_storage }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stor->possible_places }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href="storages/{{$stor->id}}">DETAIL</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

### storage_info.blade.php

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     
        <h1>Storage-info</h1>
     
        <table border="2">
            <tr><th>Storage ID</th><th>Alcohol name</th><th>count</th></tr> 
            @foreach ($storage as $stor)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $stor->id_of_storage }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ $stor->count }}</td>         
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Как это сделать? + к этой теме, из-за этой проблемы так же не работает SUM(sa.count), который должен мне посчитать количество всего товара в указанном складе.

Comment: Судя по всему вы не корректно объединяете таблицы. Посмотрите подробнее про JOIN'ы, например, тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/44807/

Comment: Так по тей же БД, в простом php всё работает идеально... Проблема именно тут.

Comment: Получайте данные в модели! А не в контроллере. Если вы правильно создали модель с миграцией то у вас уже всё есть останется только добавить объединение в классе модели